# local variable scope in linq anonymous method ( closure)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, closures, anonymous-methods

What is the scope of local variable declared in Linq Query.

I was writing following code

```
   static void Evaluate()
    {
        var listNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i);
        int i = 10;
    }
```

Compiler flagged error on line int i=10, stating

```
A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else
```

I am unable to understand why this error is coming.

My understanding was that `i` will become out of scope after first line (in foreach loop). So `i` can be declared again.

Actual behavior is that `i` cannot be accessed after first line (in foreach loop), which is correct. But `i` cannot be declared again. This seems strange.

EDIT
This is a following question based on response by Andras. The answer is very good, but causes further doubts.

```
  static void Evaluate3()
    {
        var listNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i);
        var listNumbers1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i);
    }
```

Based on the logic of function Evaluate that .Select(i=>i), and int i=10, both i, are local to function block and hence complication error.

Function Evaluate3 should not compile as well as there are two i in the method block, but it is compiling successfully without any warning/error.

Question, Either both Evaluate and Evaluate3 should not compile, or both should compile.

Comment: this problem is not related to LINQ. it is related to lamda expression inside linq.
.Select (x=> x) -> yes error goes away

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of a lambda variable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494074/what-is-the-scope-of-a-lambda-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key fact to note here is that a declaration:

```
int i;
```

...takes effect across the whole enclosing scope from *start to finish* - not just from the point at which it is declared.  In .Net the declaration of a local variable is just an instruction to the compiler to reserve that name and local for the entire scope.  That means once it's declared, it's already reserved for all lines *before and after*.

In effect, it means that you should actually read `Evaluate` as:

```
static void Evaluate()  
{  
  int i;  
  var listNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i);  
  i = 10;
}
```

And if you do write your method accordingly, you'll see that the the compiler error occurs on the lambda declaration instead - which is perfectly reasonable.  Thankfully, the C# compiler is clever enough, from a human perspective, to recognise that ordering of code is important to *us*, and it actually assigns the compiler error to whichever source line is the second or subsequent declaration; hence why in your version of `Evaluate` it happens on the line `int i = 10;`.  With this knowledge of the actual lifetime of the function's local `i`, the compiler is correct: the use of `i` there ***will*** conflict with the earlier use of `i` in the lambda.

You can use explicit scoping to avoid this:

```
static void Evaluate()  
{
  var listNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => i);
  {
    int i = 10;
  }
}
```

In the case of `Evaluate3` you simply note that whilst both lambdas share the parent function scope, they also have their own, and it's in there that their `i`s are declared - and that's why they don't interfere with each other (they are, in effect, sibling scopes).

Incidentally `Evaluate` and `Evaluate3` can ultimately be simplified to this:

```
static void Evaluate()
{
  { 
    int i;
  }
  int i; //<-- error
}

static void Evaluate3()
{
   { 
     int i;
   }
   { 
     int i;
   }
   //fine here - both i's are in different scopes.
}
```

And it's actually the second scenario here that I've used explicit scoping for before - that is, in different scopes within the same function, where the `i` actually has a different type in each.  Like I say - I've never done it again and the code in question is no longer live :)

Comment: if you see from coding error point of view, i will also never do it again. It is just i have faced, and had mind blank on this one.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have put a follow up question based on the response.

Comment: i have understood the behavior and explanation. My take is that it is not scope of parent method block (Evaluate in first code, Evaluate3 on second code) which is causing the issue. It is the scope inside Anonymous method which is causing the issue. 
Since anonymous method can access local variables of outside function, In Evaluate, it is causing error as it is seeing two i. In Evaluate3, Since no lamda expression is seeing two i, no warning/error is flagged.
I want to hear your opinion. If you agree, please update the answer with better word. I am not as expressive as you are.

Comment: @Tilak  I've boiled it down to brass-tacks in my updated answer again. It *is* all to do with the declaration of the local in the method.

Answer (score 1):

From [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664742.aspx):

```
The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable.
```

Your lambda `i => i` is inside the scope of the local variable `int i = 10` even though it is declared beforehand. Rather than throwing an error because you're using `i` before it is declared, the compiler is helpfully pointing out that you've already used `i` to refer to something else and that this declaration would change that.

EDIT: Following your update:

In the first case, your first `i` is enclosed within the lambda, but your second `i` encompasses the whole `Evaluate` method *including the lambda* - hence you get the error.

In the second case, your first `i` is enclosed within its lambda, and your second `i` is enclosed within *its* lambda - neither `i` is within the scope of the other, so there is no error.

Your paragraph "Based on the logic of ... both i, are local to function block..." is incorrect - the first `i` is not local to the function block but to the lambda.

Comment: @Grant The first `i` is indeed "local to the `Select` statement". However, the second `i` is local to the whole `Evaluate()` method, including the lambda.